# custom metric based on a event type

Tags: looker-studio

In data studio I would like the sum of total events where event action = 'foo'.

So I clicked on create new metric and typed this for my formula:

```
sum(Total Events) where Event Action == 'foo'
```

This returns "could not parse formula" error.

Since we have many types of events, I only want the total 'foo' events.

How can I create a custom metric which is all events for action 'foo'?